# Discrete Bar Chart colors nvd3.js

Tags: nvd3.js

I am using nvd3.js discrete bar http://nvd3.org/ghpages/discreteBar.html

I am inspecting the code and seen that the color is been derived inline

```
style="fill: #ffbb78; stroke: #ffbb78;"
```

I also track on the discreteBarChart function

```
color = nv.utils.getColor()
```

What I don't realizing and asking is what does color takes as a parameter ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It requires and array of colors => `['#aec7e8', '#7b94b5', '#486192']` , something like this would work.

```
var chart = nv.models.discreteBarChart()
                   .... 
                   ....
                   .color(['#aec7e8', '#7b94b5', '#486192']);
```

[NVD3](https://github.com/novus/nvd3) inherits the defaults colurs set by d3 [here](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/build/nv.d3.js#L962)

Hope it helps.

Comment: color() sets the color per dataset while barColor() sets the color per group (with automatic different shading to make the bars distinguishable). They both take arrays of colors.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use one single colour, then it can be returned from the options object like below :

```js
var options={
 ....
 colour:function(){
 return '#ff0000';
 },
 ...
 ..
}
```